# UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext in WebApi calls

Tags: webapi

I'm trying to use Async tasks in my custom web api calls in Sitecore. I've successfully followed this article http://www.agehrke.com/2015/08/web-api-controller-in-sitecore-8/#comment-18861.

However I'm afraid to enable UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext. Has anyone tried this? Could there be side effects?

Comment: I have implemented async tasks in the past and it is working as expected. **Could there be any side effects:** That depends on what operation you are running in your task.

Comment: **Note:** In my implementations, I did not enable _UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext_ which sets to default value = false